# Google's Android Basic Samples code broken - Gradle Issues

Tags: android

I'm trying to follow Google's ['Getting Started For Android Game Development'](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quickstart#before_you_begin) and have been playing around with a few hours now. But as soon as I import their project from their instructions, I'm greeted by an error that seemingly is not addressed -anywhere- on the internet. Here it is:

```html
Error:Cannot resolve external dependency com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0 because no repositories are defined.
Required by:
    :BasicSamples:unspecified
```

When I look at the gradle files too, there's common areas errors all of them too (their sample folder contains 5+ basic games each with their own build file) - mousing over buildscript, allprojects, repositories, and a number of others simply gives you the message 'cannot resolve symbol'.

Note that the only actual error shown in the entire folder of mini-games is the one above, and in the Gradle Sync messages section.

It's a little frustrating that code given from Google for a beginner's task is completely broken as is. Any help on how to resolve the issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you had success running other Gradle projects (such as one generated via the New Project option)?

Comment: Yep my other ones are working fine actually - I have two other projects using gradle that aren't having any issues.

Comment: Just cloned repository, inported project and built it without any problem. I'm runnin latest Android Studio - so Google's code is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears the [top level build.gradle](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/blob/master/BasicSamples/build.gradle) file is missing a declaration of dependencies. The `buildscript` section should read:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
    }
}
```

Comment: You are wrong. Each subproject includes top level build.gradle file, but has it's own build.gradle, which has dependencies declaration with repositories.

Comment: Thanks ian. Adding the
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
block solved the issue.

@localhost I'm not entirely sure what you mean? The fix worked, were you referring to something else? The file I edited with that change was the BasicSamples/build.gradle one, not a BasicSamples/**minigame**/build.gradle one.

Comment: @juicetin, i mean i cloned the repository from GitHub, imported it to my Android Studio and it worked without any changes from my side which means that Google's code IS NOT BROKEN, but u did something wrong while importing it.

Comment: @localhost oh that's good/interesting to know - I followed what the Google developer page said to, i.e. - download the folder, import project, and select android-basic-samples/BasicSamples/build.gradle before pressing OK. 

At that point I already got the error I mentioned - it was working perfectly for you at this stage? It was basically one step and I tried multiple times, so I wasn't able to figure out where I could've done anything wrong.

Comment: @juicetin, it's strange, but i did exactly the same and everything is OK :D